# Add csrf_token to base.html template

Tags: python, django, templates, csrf

In my django project, I'd like to add the csrf_token template tag to the base.html template. 
Just dropping the template tag in doesn't get it populated, I'd have to add it to every  view, which is not optimal.

So, is there a way to add the csrf_token on every page?

I would think this would be built into whatever view renders the base.html template.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "Just dropping the template tag in doesn't get it populated"?

Comment: In base.html adding {% csrf_token %} directly before the closing </body> tag.  I would think it the tag would render automagically.

Comment: The `csrf_token` is necessary within every form for security reasons. As long as you are using only one form in each site the form and the token can reside in your `base.html`.

Comment: You would just have to add the decorator @csrf_protect to every view function. I am not sure how is it not optimal?

Comment: Right, so instead of adding @csrf_protect to EVERY VIEW FUNCTION, isn't there a a global view function I can add it to?

Comment: @timo, I have multiple forms on a page.

Comment: Ok, so every form needs its own `{% csrf_token %}` within the opening and closing `<form>` tag.

Comment: The {% csrf_token %} does NOT have to be within the <form> tags. It can be anywhere on the page, but you have to manually grab it when you process your form.

Comment: The official [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) state to "use the `csrf_token` tag inside the `<form>` element if the form is for an internal URL". And you need to as every form needs this hidden form field with the name `csrfmiddlewaretoken`, this part is done by the template tag.

Comment: You CAN bypass that instruction for ajax forms, or perhaps, an ajax search box input.

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't know why it's not rendered, it should be inside a form element for it to work properly.

Create a form.html template and reuse it with :

```
{% include 'form.html' with form=contact_form %}
```

Place the csrf tag inside form.html